# How to identify previous ViewController loaded in IF statement

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I have an NSString called stringToDisplay, in which i would like to assign a different value if a certain ViewController was visited. How could I set this up? Is this even possible? ...example of what I want:

```
If ([prevViewController.visited] == Yes)
{
   stringToDisplay = value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a navigation controller, you can just do:

```
NSArray *views = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController *previous = [views objectAtIndex:[views count]-2];
```

where `[views objectAtIndex:[views count]-1]` is the current ViewController;

Comment: I am not using navigation view controllers, but rather the default viewcontroller nib(s). How could I edit the NSArray *views line to accommodate?

Comment: If you are just adding the new view over the previous view, you will need to have a pointer to the previous view in the new one. So if you are calling viewControllerB from viewControllerA, your viewControllerB will need to have a `viewControllerA *prevView` and when you create the viewControllerB in viewControllerA, you need to have a line `viewB.prevView = self`, and then you can use `self.prevView` in viewControllerB to access viewControllerA.